# progress bar with percentage jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, progress-bar

I am trying to develop a mobile application using jquery mobile, as I am doing the work with the web service. I want it to display a progress bar with percentage of completion.

Comment: Have you attempted anything?

Comment: no. I'm currently looking for a solution

Comment: Then look at http://jqueryui.com/progressbar/

Comment: I'm currently looking for a solution, such as progress bar displays hover  the page and not inside the page

Comment: Here is a simple jQuery Progress bar plugin -> [jqProgressBar](http://code-tricks.com/simple-jquery-progress-bar-plugin/)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*Full disclosure: I have written this open source plugin*

You may try the [jQuery-Mobile-Progress-Bar-with-Percentage](https://github.com/tolis-e/jQuery-Mobile-Progress-Bar-with-Percentage) plugin.

The jQuery-Mobile-Progress-Bar-with-Percentage (Tolito Progress Bar) is a plugin for jQuery Mobile which creates, manages, starts, stops, resumes and explicitly sets the value of a progress bar. In addition the constructor provides the options to set the progress bar's outer theme and inner filling theme on the basis of the jQuery Mobile standard themes, to show a percentage completion counter, to set whether the progress bar has normal or mini size, to define the interval which specifies the filling frequency rate, to configure the max value of the outer bar and set the initial value of the filling inner bar. The JavaScript prototype chaining method has been used in order to enable the chaining of separate method calls where each call is made on the same instance.

**EDITED:**
The new version **1.0.3** contains functionality to **stop and/or resume** the progress bar and to **explicitly set the progress bar's value**. This fits to the cases where some AJAX requests need to be performed and in each successful response the progress bar value has to be set explicitly in order to represent the actual progress status. Furthermore an event is triggered when the progress bar is completed.

The JavaScript prototype chaining method has been used in order to enable the chaining of separate method calls where each call is made on the same instance.

The following piece of code configures, builds and initializes a progress bar:

```
TolitoProgressBar('progressbar')
    .setOuterTheme('b')
    .setInnerTheme('e')
    .isMini(true)
    .setMax(100)
    .setStartFrom(0)
    .setInterval(10)
    .showCounter(true)
    .logOptions()
    .build()
    .run();
```

Example with mini progress bar:

[image]

Example with a normal progress bar inside a dialog:

[image]

Example with an overlay which includes a normal progress bar:

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

**CSS**

```
.progress { position:relative; width:260px; border: 1px solid #ddd; padding: 1px; border-radius: 3px; }
.bar { background-color: #B4F5B4; width:0%; height:20px; max-width:240px; border-radius: 3px; background-image: url(../images/pbar-ani.gif); }
.percent { position:absolute; display:inline-block; top:3px; left:48%; }
```

**JS**

Change duration parameter to your estimated time.

```
$(".bar").animate({width:'100%'},{duration:5000,step:function(now,fx){
    var pc = parseInt(now)+'%';
    $(".percent").html(pc);}
});
```

Comment: Can you include supporting files and how html fit together? Not sure where to place progress and percent. (can figure out from CSS, I guess it's not worth the effort)