# Adding progress bar for file being downloaded using phonegap and Jquery

Tags: android, jquery, cordova

I am trying to have a progress bar for download operation. Here is my code. I am not able to set the value in the progress bar even though i m able to get the value

```
<div id = "progressbar" class="progress progress-striped active" style="display:none"><div id="progress-label" class ="bar">Loading...</div></div>
<script>
        $(function() {
                    var progressbar;
        progressbar = $( "#progressbar" ),
        progressLabel = $( ".progress-label" );
        progressbar.progressbar({
            value: false,
            change: function() {
                progressLabel.text( progressbar.progressbar( "value" ) + "%" );
            },
            complete: function() {
                progressLabel.text( "Complete!" );
            }
        });
    });

            var ft = new FileTransfer();
            $("#progressbar").show();
            ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
            perc = Math.floor((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100);
            progressbar.progressbar("value", perc);
            }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess that

```
$( "#progressbar" ).val(perc);
```

does not work ?

This may be the correct syntax to update your progressbar:

```
$("#progressbar").progressbar({
    value: 35
});
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1476573/jquery-ui-how-to-change-the-color-of-a-progressbar) (and plenty more infos).
You may try also [another way](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14120960/progress-bar-with-percentage-jquery-mobile).

Comment: $( "#progressbar" ).val(perc);

Comment: no it did not :(
its setting the value in the progress bar just once, same was the problem previously

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle of this (do not forget to link the library in "External resources")?

Answer (score 0):

I just tested this and this should work for you:

```
    var ft = new FileTransfer();
                $("#progressbar").show();
                ft.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {

                perc = Math.floor((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100);

                $("#progressbar").progressbar({value:perc}); //changed this line

                }
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help..will give it a try but for now i used an page loader. will post my results..thanks again